# MQTT Vernemq Trace Log

Tags: mqtt, trace, mqtt-vernemq, trace-logging

In MQTT Vernemq trace log in this after CONNACK and SUBSCRIBE,  hook returned ok till this working fine, the next step MQTT SEND: CID SUBACK getting delay 8seconds. However, the Broker is supposed to send the SUBACK immediately after the subscription notification without any delay. In between SUBSCRIBE and SUBACK is delayed. Reason for delayed response
there is no network issuse
what will be the reason for the delay?

Comment: One possible option is an ACL check, but without knowing how your instance is configured it's not possible say know more.